# What's a sensible workflow for deploying webserver content using git push?

Tags: nginx, web-server, git, www-data

I'd like to use git push to update my (nginx) webserver content, while still keeping things secure. One way I could do this would be to ssh to my server, `git pull` from bitbucket into `/srv/www`, and `chown -R www-data:www-data .`.

It'd be slicker, though, to be able to push it there from my home computer (a la Heroku), but I'm not sure how best to handle issues of permissions and ownership.

Does anyone have advice about the most sensible way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the book on this, given the extra complications that I 1) have the html for several different sites as submodules in a top-level project, and 2) want to keep the canonical source on bitbucket, I decided to just `ssh` in and `git pull` rather than having more moving parts.

(Thanks for the info in the other answers, which equipped me to learn about the different options.)

Answer (score 2):

If you were using your web server as a git server, you could go for the only slightly complicated approach of using git hooks (put your update code into a script and call that on every git update); some git hosts support hooks too, but that's going to be quite a lot more complicated as they'll be calling your update notifier over the network rather than running a local script

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! This site http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto seems to be a very good resource for this.

Answer (score 1):

## Preface

**Never** place any working copy inside site-tree

## Face

`git archive --remote ...` is your silver-bullet